# Users setup with misspelled name - CentOS 8

Tags: users, audit

I have a user with a misspelled username on my CentOS 8 system which I thought I had corrected but I have noticed the username is showing up in the audit log incorrectly.

The correct username is:

- Example.User

The incorrect username is:

- Exampel.User

My AUID value is showing the incorrect username.  Any pointers on how to correct this would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Once you have corrected the user name in `/etc/passwd` (read `man sudoedit` and `man 5 passwd`) the user MUST logoff and login.

Answer (score 0):

There are several places where a userid might need to be adjusted if you need to rename an account manually:

Authentication files:

- /etc/passwd
- /etc/shadow
- /etc/group
- /etc/gshadow
- /etc/subgid
- /etc/sudoers

Other files

- /etc/aliases

If you have not done so already you can search for the old username (as root) like this, and you will get a list of files in and under `/etc` still referencing the old name:

```
grep -irl Exampel.User /etc
```

You may want to change the home directory location too. For example,

```
usermod --home /home/Example.User Example.User
```

And possibly rename the local email folder, `/var/mail/Exampel.User` too.

If this person uses a GUI you may well need to update files under ~Example.User/.config - unfortunately some of these are not text files - and it may get to the point that it's easier to rename this directory out of the want and let the environment create a new graphical profile.

Once you have confirmed that the files have been updated correctly and completely the user in question *must* log off and you must check that there are no lingering processes (`ps -fu Exampel.User` and `ps -fu Example.User`) before allowing them to log in once more.